# How to solve "org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set" error?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using java-hibernate-mysql combination

When i m doing update query i m getting following error. I don't understand what is wrong with hibernate. 
Following i have posted the error which i m getting :

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [0] [update       sequence s set s.cmd_output='neox     tty1         2012-06-08 09:40 (:0)
neox     pts/1        2012-06-08 09:41 (:0)
neox     pts/0        2012-06-08 09:41 (:0)
neox     pts/2        2012-06-08 09:41 (:0)
neox     pts/3        2012-06-08 12:48 (deval-PC.local.lan)
[neox@localhost ~]$ ', s.cmd_output_time='2012-06-08 12:48:58' where s.id=43]
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:106)
at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.executeUpate(QueryImpl.java:85)
at db_model.sequence_db.insert_Sequence_new(sequence_db.java:242)
at views.CaptureNavigationView$10.widgetSelected(CaptureNavigationView.java:555)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at nspl.test.ui.Application.start(Application.java:43)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at    org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLaunch    er.java:110)
at     org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Can anybody tell me why i m getting this error?

Comment: Try reading the error?  You have some parameters in your update statement which haven't been bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you executing an sql string with the `:` character in them? If so, Hibernate is expecting a parameter and you're not setting it.

```
String sql = "update SomeTable set someColumn = :value";
```

Using this you would usually set the value parameter using

```
SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
query.setString("value", "Some value with : in it");
```

or similar. I can only assume your value has a `:` in it which does not signify a parameter so you should build this as a string and set that as the parameter.

Comment: When i manually execute this query in mysql database it runs perfectly. But i dont understand what's the problem of hibernate

Comment: When i manually enter the above query directly in mysql it works : <code> UPDATE sequence s SET s.cmd_output='neox tty1 2012-06-08 09:40 (:0) neox pts/1 2012-06-08 09:41 (:0) neox pts/0 2012-06-08 09:41 (:0) neox pts/2 2012-06-08 09:41 (:0) neox pts/3 2012-06-08 12:44 (deval-PC.local.lan) [neox@localhost ~]$ ', s.cmd_output_time='2012-06-08 12:44:30' WHERE s.id=26 </code>

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the part in bold here : 2012-06-08 09:41 (**:0**)

You should not concatenate String to build your query but instead use parameters. It is the only way to escape the : characters in hql queries.

Example :

```
String param1 = "neox     tty1         2012-06-08 09:40 (:0)\n" +
                "neox     pts/1        2012-06-08 09:41 (:0)\n"+
                "neox     pts/0        2012-06-08 09:41 (:0)\n" +
                "neox     pts/2        2012-06-08 09:41 (:0)\n" +
                "neox     pts/3        2012-06-08 12:48 (deval-PC.local.lan)\n" +
                "[neox@localhost ~]$ ";
String param2 = "2012-06-08 12:48:58";
String id = 43;

String hqlQuery = "update sequence s set s.cmd_output = :cmd_output, " +
                  "s.cmd_output_time = :cmd_output_time where s.id = :cmdId";

getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedParam(hqlQuery, 
   new String[] {"cmd_output", "cmd_output_time", "cmdId"},
   new Object[] {param1, param2, id});
```

Comment: Thank you very much but the values are not static. It may change

Comment: When i manually enter the above query directly in mysql it works :
<code>
    UPDATE sequence s SET s.cmd_output='neox     tty1         2012-06-08 09:40 (:0)
    neox     pts/1        2012-06-08 09:41 (:0)
    neox     pts/0        2012-06-08 09:41 (:0)
    neox     pts/2        2012-06-08 09:41 (:0)
    neox     pts/3        2012-06-08 12:44 (deval-PC.local.lan)
    [neox@localhost ~]$ ', s.cmd_output_time='2012-06-08 12:44:30' WHERE s.id=26 </code>

Comment: Yes, they change, so you have them in a variable somewhere ? Just use this variable (instead of param1) into the last getHibernateTemplate line of code, and you're good.

Answer (score 0):

to summarise

1.you should set all named params 
2. when you dynamically set values to name param, there should not be : in it.
   in case you have : you should use string concatenation and drop the approach of named param. as said in first answer.

Comment: I understood your answer. But the value will change everytime. It cannot be same everytime. The value which i got is from linux server

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass the named  parameter query by puttong if condition when it is dynamic.

So you make it as a query string and then append your named parameter by putting a condition.

You don't have to drop the named parameter approach.