# Hibernate QueryException Not all named parameters have been set:

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

When my query is executed i receive stack

```
    Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [param0] [select count(generatedAlias0.id)
from Position as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.rank=:param0]
```

Method where is executed

```
public Long CountPosition(Rank aRank, List<Long> Status, List<Long> aStatusInternal) {
        QueryBuilder<PozycjaWRankingu> aQuery = queryCountLarge();
        aQuery.whereEquals("rank", aRank);
        aQuery.whereInNotEmpty("status", Status);
        aQuery.whereInNotEmptyAndNotEquals("internal.state", aStatusInternal);
        return aQuery.countLarge();
    }
```

And finally Query Builder

```
public static <T> QueryBuilder<T> createCountLarge(EntityManager aEntityManager, Class<T> aClass) {
        QueryBuilder r = new QueryBuilder();
        r.em = aEntityManager;
        r.criteriaBuilder = r.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        r.criteria = ret.criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
        r.root = ret.criteria.from(aClass);
        r.criteria.select(ret.criteriaBuilder.count(ret.root.get("id")));

        return r;
    }
```

Any idea where is might be a problem ?

Edit
queryCountLarge() returns

```
QueryBuilder.createCountLarge(em, myClass);
```

Comment: Can you tell us what your function called "queryCountLarge()" does ?

Comment: I edit queryCountLarge() returns createCountLarge

Comment: Where did you write this: `select count(generatedAlias0.id)
from Position as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.rank=:param0`? It seems to me that you didn't explicitly set that parameter to be a value so the query can't execute. This, at least has been my experience.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve "org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set" error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944733/how-to-solve-org-hibernate-queryexception-not-all-named-parameters-have-been-s)